# How to programmatically center align drawn objects in a specific way

Tags: java, android, actor, centering

Stop me if you've heard this one.

So, I have a ship on screen (working in Android Java here) for my own version of Galaga. It's possible to have more than one captured ship in my version and they move to just ahead of the player ship to act as a meatshield.

The issue is trying to get them to sit nicely in place. I could have any number of ships so I want to ensure I can dynamically arrange them based on how many the player has attached to them.

When one captured ship is present, it could be aligned with the player ship.

When an even number of captured ships are present, they sit evenly across a central point that sits right in the center of the player ship but so they cover the player.

[Even Number of Captured Ships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IPbn.jpg)

When an odd number of captured ships are present, they sit with one equal to the players position and then sit either side neatly.

[Odd Number of Captured Ships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E75Zg.jpg)

Is there a way of doing this programmatically? These ships have got to move around with the player so trying to use a built in group or something doesn't seem sensible. But if I missed something in the API that would be useful, please let me know.

Thanks for reading. I wait anxiously for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There definitely is a way of doing this, you just have to be creative. Here is some Java pseudocode that would do what you want. let `mainX` be the x position of the main spaceship, `numShips` be the number of shield spaceships you have, `shipLength` be the horizontal length of the ships (I assume they are all the same) and let `shieldX[]` be an array of the x positions of the shield spaceships. Then, to make code that fills `shieldX[]` with the values that you want, we have (also assuming all these things are ints, but that can be easily changed if they are not.) :

```
 // Assume numShips, mainX, and shipLength have already been declared 
 int[] shieldX = new int[numShips];
 // Determine if odd or even number of ships
 boolean isOdd = numShips % 2; 
 if (isOdd) {
     // Middle shield ship index will be aligned with main Ship
     int mid = (numShips - 1)/ 2;
     shieldX[mid] = mainX; 
     // Place the ships on right and left sequentially. 
     for (int i = 1; i <= mid; i++) {
         // Calculate offset for every pair of ships.
         int offset = i * shipLength;
         shieldX[mid - i] = mainX - offset;
         shieldX[mid + i] = mainX + offset;
     }
} else {
    // First calculate the half length of the ships. 
    int half = shipLength / 2; 
    // Left Middle shield ship index will be half aligned with main Ship
    int midL = numShips / 2 - 1; 
    // Right middle shield ship index will be half aligned with main ship
    int midR = numShips / 2;
    // If we are even, then we can go straight into the for loops, similar to above
    for (int i = 0; i < midR; i++) {
        // Again calculate offset. This time include half lengths.
        int offsetL = i * shipLength + (shipLength / 2);
        // Now set values
        shieldX[midL - i] = mainX - offset;
        shieldX[midR + i] = mainX + offset;
    }
}
```

Note that I wrote this somewhat quickly and did not test it yet (wanted to get you an answer relatively quickly, I will edit the answer if I find an off-by-one error or something like that), but the idea should be there. I hope I am answering your question and did not misinterpret it, please let me know if I did. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. That works pretty well! I had a stab at doing something similar and this works far better. For one, it's more elegant than my bodged together maths. It's not my strongest suit with some of these things. I'm going to hang onto this snippet. There's other places this would be useful in the game game. Worked with little change too, mostly had to just add in the relevant information here and there.

Comment: Yep, no problem, glad I could help. Let me know if you have other questions about this, too.